# Converting GeoJSON to MySQL

Tags: mysql, geojson

I don't have much experience in means of working with MySQL, much less extending it. I'd like to import the SimpleGeo data into a MySQL database. Here's an example of an entry:

```
{ "geometry" : { "coordinates" : [ -87.547968999999995,
          33.151769000000002
        ],
      "type" : "Point"
    },
  "id" : "SG_1uDW3Q0HX5ZQPMw1q3XcGF_33.151769_-87.547969@1293731398",
  "properties" : { "address" : "6000 Old Greensboro Rd",
      "city" : "Tuscaloosa",
      "classifiers" : [ { "category" : "Restaurant",
            "subcategory" : "",
            "type" : "Food & Drink"
          } ],
      "country" : "US",
      "href" : "http://api.simplegeo.com/1.0/features/SG_1uDW3Q0HX5ZQPMw1q3XcGF_33.151769_-87.547969@1293731398.json",
      "name" : "Godfather's Pizza",
      "owner" : "simplegeo",
      "phone" : "+1 205 464 0000",
      "postcode" : "35405",
      "province" : "AL",
      "website" : "www.dinerrestaurants.com"
    },
  "type" : "Feature"
}
```

I'd like to put this into a MySQL database and have the ability to run geospacial queries on it. I understand that there's a spatial extension to MySQL but I have absolutely no idea where to start with it. The MySQL documentation makes it sound like it's already a part of MySQL but is it really? And how could I run through the whole (8 GB) file and put it into a geospacial database? Could I use PHP? (I'm comfortable with PHP.)

I know I'm asking for a lot here, but any help would be great.

Comment: What is the mysql version?

Comment: Do you have the mysql tables ready for use or need to develop?

Comment: This data that you show, this came from POST, GET, browser, jquery, etc.? what is the technology that output this kind of data?

Comment: `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.32, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2` is the version. I haven't made tables for this yet but I assume the JSON is going to be flattened and the coordinates are going to be wrapped up in some kind of geometry data type (`point` seems the way to go from the MySql docs.) I'm not sure what output this data... it came from a SimpleGeo dump. There are at least a million other entries like this in a file. As I said... it's 8GB in size.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out! The json file was separated by new lines, so I could just go line by line and parse the json and submit it to my MySQL! Problem Solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(string in GeoJson Format) function in MySql request.

Comment: this kind of answer should be comment that dont explain well,,

Answer (score 0):

3 days, but found a simple solution that I want to share.  Works on MySQL version 8 and PHP version 8.  I did not try any other versions.

```
$str = '{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1],[0,0]]]]}]}';
```

---or get from file---

```
$str = file_get_contents("1234.json");
```

Problem that I had was that the GeoJson data and MySql statement has both single and double quotes.  "<<<EOD" solves this problem.  Here is the working solution.  MySql column set as "Geometry" and "null".

```
$sql = <<<EOD
    UPDATE table SET column =  ST_SRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJson('
    EOD.$str.<<<EOD
    '),3857) WHERE column = anything 
    EOD;
```

Note:  Must start a newline after using <<<EOD

And to test the code, point inside polygon

```
$sql = "SELECT * from column WHERE ST_Contains
(column, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(.5 .5)',3857))";

$result = $link->query($sql);  
foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['column'];
}
```

and point outside of Polygon

```
 $sql = "SELECT * from column WHERE ST_Contains
(column, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(2 2)',3857))";
```